# Tkinter strange behavior on destroy()

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am developing an application on Tkinter, Python 2.7.
In one of my processes I build a portion of my window (root) with 26 widgets:
    23 Labels, 2 Buttons and 1 Entry.
While building them I keep adding their names to a list for further destroying
when their use is finished. For that I use the press of one of the buttons ("Done")
to read the list created and destroy() them inside a "for" loop.
The widgets get destroyed erratically, not in the order on the list. And I need
several presses of the button to finish it.
I found out of frustration, not insight, that if the list is reversed() in
the "for" loop they all get "destroyed" in the first attempt.
Is this an expected behaviour? Very puzzling!
I am ready to post the portion of my application with the strange behavior
expunged of unnecessary code unless somebody already knows the reason for it.
I am still busting my chops with Python and not ready to use Classes...
Thank you!

I am including the relevant portion of my program. I edited the original to reduce it size. Tested the edited version and it has the same behavior. I commented some of my code to show where to correct.
Happy that Mr. Oakley has taken interest. I am not sure if on transcribing my code the proper indentation was not affected.

My code:

```
# testdestroy.py
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Information container')
root.geometry('1160x900+650+50')

global todestroy, screen, font1, lbl1txt, lbl2txt
global col, row, colincr, rowincr, bxincr, entries

todestroy = []
screen = ''
col = 10
row = 10
font1 = 'verdana 12 bold '
colincr = 370
rowincr = 40
bxincr = 145

entries = {' Last updated: ' : '11/08/2016 at 11:55',
            ' Login id: ' : 'calfucura',
            ' Password: ': 'munafuca',
            'card number' : '1234567890',
            'check number': '445',
            'expiry' : '12/06/2018',
            'PIN' : '9890', 
            'Tel:' : '1-800-234-5678',
            'emergency' : 'entry nine',
            'use for' : 'gas, groceries'}

def position(col, row, what):       # returns the position for the place command
    colincr = 370
    rowincr = 40
    bxincr = 145
    if what == 'down':
        row += rowincr
        col -= colincr
    if what == 'side':
        col += colincr
    if what == 'button1':
        row += rowincr
        col += colincr - bxincr
    if what == 'button':
        col -= bxincr
    if what == 'reset':
        col = col
        row = row
    return col, row

def done(event):                        #  Button "Done"
    print 'Done pressed'
    for name in todestroy:     # DOES NOT WORK!!!!
                               # THIS WORKS in the previous line: 
                               # for name in reversed(todestroy):
        name.destroy()
        todestroy.remove(name)

def accept(event):                      # Button "Accept"
    print 'Name to show: ', entry1.get()
    scr2d1(entries)

def scr2d():                            # Name to show
    lbl1txt = 'Enter name to show: '
    screen = 'scr2d'
    scr2(lbl1txt)
#    scr2d1(entries)

def scr2(lbl1txt):
    global todestroy, col, row, entry1
    lbl1 = Label(root, text = lbl1txt, anchor = E, width = 25, font = font1)
    entry1 = Entry(root, width = 25, show = '*', font = font1)
    Accept = Button(root, text = 'Accept', font = font1, bg = 'green', width = 9)
    cmd = eval('Accept'.lower())
    Accept.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', cmd)
    col, row = position(200, 200, 'reset')
    lbl1.place(x = col, y = row)
    col, row = position(col, row, 'side')
    entry1.place(x = col , y = row )
    col, row = position(col, row, 'button1')
    Accept.place(x = col, y = row)
    todestroy = []
    todestroy.extend([lbl1, entry1, Accept])

def scr2d1(entries):                # show entries
    global todestroy, col, row
    lblup = 1
    lbl = 'lbl' + str(lblup)
    lbl = Label(root, text = 'Entry', font = font1, width = 20 )
    row = rowincr * 7
    col = 600
    col, row = position(col, row, 'down')
    lbl.place(x = col, y = row)
    todestroy.append(lbl)
    lblup += 1
    lbl = 'lbl' + str(lblup)
    lbl = Label(root, text = 'Contents', font = font1, width = 20)
    col, row = position(col, row, 'side')
    lbl.place (x = col, y = row)
    todestroy.append(lbl)
    for name in sorted(entries):
        lblup += 1
        lbl = 'lbl' + str(lblup)
        lbl = Label(root, text = name, bg = 'yellow', font = font1, width = 25, anchor = E)
        col, row = position(col, row, 'down')
        lbl.place(x = col, y = row)
        todestroy.append(lbl)
        lblup += 1
        lbl = 'lbl' + str(lblup)
        lbl = Label(root, text = entries[name], bg = 'yellow', font = font1, width = 25, anchor = W)
        col, row = position(col, row, 'side')
        lbl.place(x = col , y = row)
        todestroy.append(lbl)
    cmd = eval('done')
    Done = Button(root, text = 'Done', font = font1, bg = 'green', width = 9)
    Done.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', cmd)
    col, row = position(col, row, 'button1')
    Done.place(x = col, y = row)
    todestroy.append(Done)

scr2d()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Don't post "a portion of [your] application". Instead, reduce it down to a small, working program that illustrates the problem.

Comment: are you aware that deleting a widget will destroy it, and all of its children? You don't need to destroy each widget one-by-one.

Comment: @BryanOakley I designed my program with a single root window and no frames. I keep that root window for everything I do. To use my code enter any character(s) in "Name to show" and press "Accept". Probably I am committing "code sepuku' but... I am starting in Tkinter and found frames not manageable yet.Thanks!

Comment: Most of the code you posted is unrelated to the problem, and makes it hard to see the real problem.

Comment: @BrianOakley I am surprised by what you say. If you run my code and entered any character or characters in "Name to show" and pressed "Accept" a new series of labels will display plus a button "Done". Pressing "Done will attempt to destroy all that is displayed in the window. It will fail unless you change the iteration of the list "todestroy" to reversed(). I have run the code before posting. Needed to post all the code to show the problem. Anyhow, thanks for trying.

Comment: To show the problem, you don't need all of the widgets -- only having a couple is sufficient. You also don't need the different kinds of buttons; the same problem will show up if you use only labels, for example. The point of creating an [mcve](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is to help you understand your own problem. The process of reproducing the problem with as few lines of code as possible can be very instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are altering the list as you iterate over it, which is not something you should do. The reason that it works with `reversed` is because you are iterating over a copy of the original list. You get the same result if you use `for name in todestroy[:]`, which also iterates over a copy of the list.

The quickest solution is to not remove anything from the list,and simply reset the list after you've deleted everything:

```
def done(event): 
    global todestroy
    for name in todestroy:
        name.destroy()
    todestroy = []
```

A better solution would be to put all of the widgets you plan to destroy into a `Frame`. You can then destroy just the frame, and it will destroy all of its child widgets.

Comment: @BrianOakley I am glad you took the time to respond. A fine point about my list! When I started working on it I tried to use Frame but was having problems placing my items because it seems Frames grow only when you put widgets on them and it was difficult to see the results at the moment of debugging. I will give Frames another go when I am more confident on what I am doing. This is my first attempt at Tkinter. Many thanks, I don't like "mysteries"...